# django and mysql - select distinct column with filters

Tags: mysql, django, distinct

Suppose, I have a table with 3 columns:

```
create table t1 (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int)
```

I want to return a list of distinct values of `c2` after applying filters on `c1`, `c2` and `c3`.

At the SQL level, I can do this easily:

```
select distinct (c1) from t1 where c1=10 and c2>30 and c3 in (1,2,3)
```

What is the best way to do so in Django?

I don't want to use .raw SQL since the filters are dynamic and it will be a nightmare to build the appropriate SQL query (there are more than 30 columns in the real table).

Is there a way to create a `queryset` with filters against all the table columns that will return only sub columns of the table? if so the distinct() would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just use .distinct()

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Please note that you have to use Postgresql to use distinct on fields not on row.

Comment: .distinct() doesn't do the trick here. Lets say that two rows are returning from the filter: row1: c1=1, c2=1 and c3=1 and row2: c1=1, c2=2, c3=2. my serializer returns just column c1 so in this two rows will be returned with the same values c1=1. the distinct() is looking at all the fields in the queryset and since that c2 has two distinct values, it will not work

Comment: So you have to return more fields in serializer or switch to postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work but I know that this is not a good solution. I cant believe that there is no way to do that with the framework and I am sure that I am missing something! The solution below works for me but it has limitations. If I am fetching 10 rows from the database and then remove 2 duplicates, I am only returning 8 rows to the client (I can solve this by getting one row at a time and checking for duplicate and avoid calling the Serializer but in my case the below was good enough). However, as I said, I can't believe that there is no simple way to do that with the framework

```
class items(models.Model):   
    c1 = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    c2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True) 
    c3 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)


class ItemsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = items
        fields = ('c1',)
```

The view:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def items_list(request):

    #add some filters on c1,c2 and c3
    queryset = queryset.filter(c2__in=array)

    serializer = ItemsSerializer(queryset, many=True)

    #dont return the serializer data but remove duplicate
    #return Response(serializer.data)

    new_list= OrderedDict((frozenset(item.items()),item) for item in serializer.data).values()

    return Response(new_list)
```